# Element change with VUE

Tags: html, vue.js

I am somewhat new to this, but I have not managed to find something to solve my problem

What I'm trying to do is change this

```
<img src="@/assets/images/layout/topbar/magnifier.svg" height="24" width="24" />
```

For this

```
<input class="letralogin" :placeholder="InicialLogin">
```

When my parameter contains a value "InitialLogin"

```
data: () => ({
  InitialLogin: Name,
}),
```

To be more clear, I am looking for a function that helps me hide "img" when my "InitialLogin" parameter is not null and show "input"

Comment: If you're just trying to hide/show something why not use `v-if` or `v-show`? Like: `v-if="initialLogin !== null"`. If you're trying to dynamically change the type of the element itself then you'll need to use `<component is="computedToDetermineTheType">`

Comment: I already tried this '<img src="@/assets/images/layout/topbar/profile.svg" height="24" width="24" v-if="initialLogin === null" />' and ´ <a class="img-button" href="#" v-if="initialLogin !== null">´ But it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with

```
<img src="@/assets/images/layout/topbar/magnifier.svg" height="24" width="24" v-show="InitialLogin == null"/>


<input class="letralogin" :placeholder="InicialLogin" v-model="InitialLogin" v-show="InitialLogin != null">
```

or

```
<div v-if="InitialLogin == null">
  <img src="@/assets/images/layout/topbar/magnifier.svg" height="24" width="24"/>
</div>

<div v-else>
  <input class="letralogin" :placeholder="InicialLogin" v-model="InitialLogin" />
</div>
```